# Fancytree addNode function not working inside for loop

Tags: javascript, fancytree

I want to move some nodes from one fancy tree to another based on a condition. So in a for loop, for every node I am checking the condition and add it to second fancy tree using addNode() function.

But inside the for loop addNode function is not working.

Here is my forloop code.
*'toNodeID'* is the id of the fancy tree to which nodes need to be moved. '*selectedValue*' is some string value

```
 $.each(selNodes, function (node, selNode) {
                        if (selNode != null) {
                            if (toNode.tree == $('#toNodeID').fancytree("getTree")) { 
                                if (selNode.tooltip != selectedValue) {                                   
                                    toNode.addNode(node,'after);                  
                                }
                            }                           
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
toNode.addChildren(node);
```

to add a child node of toNode.